# Are "ne" and "que" sometimes dropped in spoken French?

Tags: prononciation

I have heard that French people most of the time drop `ne` and sometimes they drop `que`.

Dropping the `ne`
https://youtu.be/DKfwvE3WK1M?t=201

She don't say `qui ne...`, only `qui...`

Is it when when `ne...pas` is available?

Dropping the `que`
https://youtu.be/DKfwvE3WK1M?t=56

He say `ainsi ma trousse`, not `ainsi que ma trousse`.

**Question:**

When should I drop the `que` and `ne`?

Comment: You're mishearing the last one, they've dropped the vowel of que, but the /k/ is present.

Comment: @Eauquidort No. He don't say "k" as "ansik".

Comment: @Daniel Listen carefully, Amir definitely pronounces *ainsi **qu'ma** trousse*. I don't know if there are cases where ***que*** is dropped in French, but this is not one of them.

Comment: I second @jlliagre here- it's hard to catch, but he does say "ainsi qu'ma".

Comment: Trying to think of times you would drop the whole word "que" and coming up short

Comment: _Alors, j'avais trois cahiers, trois livres, ainsi que ma trousse et ma règle_. La question de la prononciation et de l'omission nous fait un peu oublier qu'il s'agit de la locution conjonctive _ainsi que_ qui n'est ni _ainsi_ ni _que_ seul. Dans l'énumération on voit mal comment la conjonction serait créée avec l'adverbe seul...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a difference between written and spoken French.

**Written French**

Ideally, in written French you would never drop any of those, unless you're talking in a really unformal context, like students or friends conversations. But even with friends, if you can avoid dropping words in writing, it won't hurt you and will definitely not make you seem too formal.

**Spoken French**

In spoken French, it gets tricky. You can pretty much drop the "ne" in most cases, even at work. I fail to find a sentence where dropping the "ne" would be an issue. If you need to show a **very high** amount of respect for the person you're talking to, don't drop it. Otherwise, it doesn't really matter.

The `que`, however, is not entirely dropped in most cases. In your example, as people said in the comments, the `que` is not dropped. `ainsi que ma trousse` becomes `ainsi qu'ma trousse` and the `qu` is almost silent. The two syllables of `que ma` merge into one syllable, which is why you can't hear the `qu` unless your ear is really trained for it. `ainsi ma trousse` doesn't make sense in French in that context, and that's why there is absolutely no doubt that the `qu` is pronounced here.

As opposed to the `ne`, there are very few instances where you can really drop the `que` in spoken French. One example that comes to mind would be `qu'est-ce que` becoming `qu'est-ce`. For example, in spoken French, it's not that rare hearing someone say `qu'est-ce t'en penses` instead of `qu'est-ce que tu en penses`.

That being said, if you don't drop the `ne` and you don't drop the `que`, you will not sound weird in most cases. People will notice you're not a native speaker anyway, so my advice, even though not asked for, would be to keep the `ne` and keep the `que`. That will help you with written French and you can always shorten things up later based on your conversations with native speakers.

Comment: _Honore les grands, (ne) méprise les petits_. Ou : _(Que) veux-tu ?_. L'idée d'affirmer si on peut omettre ou pas un mot indépendamment de sa nature, de son emploi ou de sa combinaison en locution est peu utile voire futile à mon avis et il faut plutôt qualifier l'emploi du mot pour déterminer si par exemple il constitue la seule particule de négation sur laquelle s'appuierait la phrase, et dans un tel contexte il serait surprenant que l'oral s'en passe davantage que l'écrit. Le fait qu'_ainsi ma trousse_ ne corresponde pas au contexte n'explique pas le besoin d'avoir _que_ pour la locution.

Comment: @baied'euzellecité En effet, les transgressions verbales sont difficiles à encadrer de règles. C'est d'ailleurs pourquoi je suggère de conserver les mots à l'oral comme à l'écrit, puis d'adapter son langage avec l'expérience.